# How would I go about converting a change in capacitance into frequency?

Tags: circuit-analysis, sensor, integrated-circuit

I have to make a model for a pressure sensor. The sensor measures the pressure by changing the capacitance. I only have the datasheet for that.

Summary: pressure>> diaphragm deflection >> change in capacitance.

Now I do not know very well how the signal conditioning inside the sensor works.

There is only one circuit diagram with timer input. So I guess is that the capacitance change is translated into frequency change, and the frequency is determined using a μC.

My questions:

- How can I calculate frequency as a function of C and resistor according to the wiring diagram in the datasheet?
- Do you think that there is in front of the circuit a signal generator whose frequency changes with capacitance change?

Circuit:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide a link to the sensor's manufacturer datasheet. Also, please explain what a "Drcuk" is.

Comment: And a Diphigram.

Comment: The block diagram shows voltage output, not frequency output.

Comment: The sensor works with both Analog and Sent protocol. and I just need the value of Counter and not the voltage. the link for the sensor :https://www.sensata.com/sites/default/files/a/sensata-ops-oil%20pressure%20sensors-datasheet.pdf

Comment: What's the source of the "circuit diagram with timer input"? Please share, as well as other relevant data...

Comment: i would like to share it but i cant because of the data protection. but there is no helpful info inside there is just mechanical drawings

Comment: It would seem that the three pins consist of a **ground**, a DC input voltage to power the sensor's electronics, perhaps +5V DC connected to \$ V_{SUPPLY} \$, and the pin that contains **analog output voltage** that varies between ground and DC input voltage. Simulating this output voltage would require a much more detailed data sheet.

Comment: @glen_geek yes but my question is, if I give Square Signal to PIN2, will this signal which associated with the Timer Input change with Capacity Change (Cf)?

Comment: Simulating those signal-processing steps 1,2,3,4,5 seems foolish. A simulator might start with step 1 and proceed directly to step 5 (analog voltage output). Some internal details of signal delays, response times, of steps 2,3,4 might be simulated by analog transfer functions or time constants. We would likely bypass the C-to-frequency-to-voltage steps.

Answer (score 2):

A typical way to do this is to use a 555 timer in astable mode.  A lower capacitance will generate a faster square wave.

Duty cycle will be greater than 50%, by nature of the 555 timer circuit.  You can divide the frequency by two if you need 50%

Comment: thats what i know. but here i do not know which timer. i just have the above showen circuit diagram. thanks

Comment: @Samuel He just told you which timer - the 555. The original design probably doesn't use a 555, it likely uses a microcontroller with a built-in timer peripheral to detect the timing and calculate frequency

Comment: @DerStrom8 you mean one mikrokonroller produce signal or with another Timer and at the same time measure the frequency of this signal right ?

Comment: @Samuel you're not making any sense at all. I can't even follow what you just asked. For that matter, I can't even follow your original question - it's completely nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know for sure what the sensor does inside.

What is certain is that the module you linked to has a voltage output rather than a frequency output:

[image]

You clipped your image a little too much.  5 is the output, and is clearly a voltage proportional to the pressure.

The datasheet gives no hint as to how the capacitance change is converted into a voltage.

Comment: if you have looked in the data sheet, you could see that it is working with 2 Modes Analog and Digital with Freq.

Comment: It says "analog **or** SENT."  You get one or the other, and it doesn't explain what SENT means.  I take it to be a proprietary serial protocol on one pin.

Comment: SENT = Single Edge Nibble Transmission (https://www.sae.org/publications/technical-papers/content/2011-01-1034/)